# Flutter cache mechanism for Dio retrofit sub library

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

i my application i'm using `Dio`'s `Retrofit` sub library, and inside that i'm not sure how can i define cache mechanism for that,

i found this line in `Retrofit` sample code:

```
@GET("")
Future<String> testCustomOptions(@DioOptions() Options options);
```

now how can i define cache on this `http` request?

[Retrofit](https://github.com/trevorwang/retrofit.dart) documentation:

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  final dio = Dio();   // Provide a dio instance
  dio.options.headers["Demo-Header"] = "demo header";   // config your dio headers globally
  final client = RestClient(dio);
  
  client.getTasks().then((it) => logger.i(it));
```

[dio-http-cache](https://pub.dev/packages/dio_http_cache) documentation:

```
QuickStart

Add a dio-http-cache interceptor in Dio :

dio.interceptors.add(DioCacheManager(CacheConfig(baseUrl: "http://www.google.com")).interceptor);

Set maxAge for a request :

Dio().get(
  "http://www.google.com",
  options: buildCacheOptions(Duration(days: 7)),
);
```

**my full implemented code:**

```
Provider(
   create: (_) => MyApis.create(),
),


abstract class MyApis{
  factory MyApis(Dio dio, {String baseUrl}) = _MyApis;

  @GET("/login")
  Future<HttpResponse<PageInformation>> login(@DioOptions() Options options);

  static MyApis create() {
    final dio = Dio();
    dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    dio.options.receiveTimeout = 60000;
    dio.options.connectTimeout = 120000;
    return _MyApis(dio);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add Parameter in your API Add point Call

```
Future<HttpResponse<PageInformation>> login(@DioOptions() Options options);
```

Add Interceptor in Dio

```
dio.interceptors.add(DioCacheManager(CacheConfig(baseUrl: 'YOUR BASE URL')).interceptor);
```

Create an object for Endpoint argument

```
Options options = buildCacheOptions(Duration(days: 10),forceRefresh: true);
```

Call your API End point

```
myapi.login(options)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me with recent retrofit+dio versions..

Comment: Yea it's not working